# Why does Math.round(-0.2) return -0?

Tags: javascript

I had a little problem with Javascript today:

I have a collection of values, for example:

```
US         11.3123
Brazil     -0.2291
UK          0.4501
```

I want to display with no decimal places, rounding values, so it will be displayed as:

```
US         11
Brazil     -0
UK          0
```

So, the problem is that Brazil is showing "-0" instead of "0".

Well, I can workaround easily:

```
html += '<tr><td>' + arr[i].Country + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + d3.format(arr[i].Value || 0, 0) + '</td></tr>';
```

Why does Math.round return -0 instead of 0?

**Update**

I'm using [D3.js format function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Formatting#d3_format), which transmits JavaScript behavior to output. But still, I have this doubt due to the fact that in console:

```
Math.round(-0.02)
> -0
```

Comment: Detecting minus zero is possible by seeing which limit it goes to, for example, `var x = -0; 1 / x === -Infinity; // true`. If you want to get rid of it safely, adding a `+0` to a `-0` will give `+0`, or you can use `x || 0` because `-0` is _falsy_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> the problem is that Brazil is showing "-0" instead of "0".

It must not. While @JoeFrambach and @Amdan explained that and why JS does distinguish between +0 and -0, this must not be output from your code (unless your JS engine is flawed). To cite [EcmaScript §9.8.1 *`ToString` Applied to the `Number` Type*](http://es5.github.io/#x9.8.1):

> 2. If [*the number*] is `+0` or `−0`, return the String `"0"`

No minus sign:

```
Math.round(-0.2) + '' == "0"
Math.round( 0.2) + '' == "0"
```

Comment: Actually, I was using D3's format number function. I did't remember that when I wrote the Question and missed this important info. You're right! the D3 is transmitting JS behavior with numbers to output.. But, still I had this doubt because I was playing around in console.. :)

Comment: The console output is a different thing again, it doesn't do simple stringification. `-0` is a representation that will when copy-pasted as a literal behave just like the actual result value, negative zero.

Comment: Yes, [d3 does explicitly handle negative zero](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/0cb6cd9283bc8601aee42e397d4cce40adb08925/src/locale/number-format.js#L82)

Answer (score 9):

From the ecmascript definition: http://es5.github.io/#x15.8.2.15

```
If x is NaN, the result is NaN.
If x is +0, the result is +0.
If x is −0, the result is −0.
If x is +∞, the result is +∞.
If x is −∞, the result is −∞.
If x is greater than 0 but less than 0.5, the result is +0.
If x is less than 0 but greater than or equal to -0.5, the result is −0.
```

> NOTE 2
>   The value of Math.round(x) is the same as the value of
>   Math.floor(x+0.5), except when x is −0 or is less than 0 but greater
>   than or equal to -0.5; for these cases Math.round(x) returns −0, but
>   Math.floor(x+0.5) returns +0.

Comment: I still don't get need of the spec distinct +0 from -0.

Comment: @AndréFigueiredo I don't understand the *why*, but here's another wtf: `-0 === 0 => true`. But, `1/(-0) === 1/0 => false`

Comment: @AndréFigueiredo: Basically, it involves limits. For example, when you calculate `lim [x -> Infinity] (1 / x)`, the result is `+0` if you approach it from the positive side, but `-0` if you approach it from the negative side. Given that all floating point arithmetic involves rounding, it is helpful to know whether something has been rounded to zero from left or right (i.e. if that `0` you are getting is actually `0.000000000000012` or `-0.000000000000012`). But for all intents and purposes they are the same number; however, `-Infinity` (`1 / (-0)`) and `+Infinity` (`1 / 0`) are not.

Comment: It might be worth saying that `-0` only really matters in _JavaScript_ if you're doing something where `x→0` is different to `x→-0` (e.g. _arctan_) because in all other cases it will be treated the same as `+0`